# What is the Elasticsearch.Net 2.x equivalent for IElasticSearchResponse.NumberOfRetries?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-net

I'm working on an application that uses the Elasticsearch .NET client libraries (Elasticsearch.Net and NEST) and, as part of a conversion from Elasticsearch 1.x to 2.x, I'm trying to work out the 2.x equivalents of some data that was previously exposed via `IElasticSearchResponse`.

In our 1.x implementation, we carried out the following logic inside a method that was supplied to `ConnectionSettings.SetConnectionStatusHandler()`:

```
    private static void LogElasticSearch1DotXMetrics(IElasticsearchResponse resp)
    {
        if (resp.NumberOfRetries > 0)
            PerformSomeLoggingOperationOn(resp.NumberOfRetries);
    }
```

In 2.x, I believe that the equivalent to `ConnectionSettings.SetConnectionStatusHandler()` is to pass a method to `ConnectionSettings.OnRequestCompleted()`. This method will receive an `IApiCallDetails` instance.

```
    private static void LogElasticSearch2DotXMetrics(IApiCallDetails details)
    {
        PerformSomeLoggingOperationOn(details.??????);
    }
```

I haven't been able to find an obvious equivalent for `IElasticSearchResponse.NumberOfRetries` on `IApiCallDetails`. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Could it be details.AuditTrail.Sum(x => x.Node.FailedAttempts)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've put this question to Elasticsearch support and am summarising their response here in case anyone else finds it useful.

There is no direct equivalent to NumberOfRetries in Elasticsearch.NET 2.x. However, there is an event for the case when the maximum number of retries is reached.

```
var maxRetriesReached = callDetails.AuditTrail
    .Any(a => a.Event == AuditEvent.MaxRetriesReached);
```

Alternatively if you're really interested in the number of retries, rather than whether or not a query was abandoned, you could also observe the audit trail for BadResponse events.

```
var badResponses = callDetails.AuditTrail
    .Any(a => a.Event == AuditEvent.BadResponse);
```